# TYPO3 custom extension templates

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid, extbase

I am currently working on a new website with TYPO3 and now I am facing a big problem with template/cache.

**Environment:**

- Extension "**Portfolio**" adds a new content element with Extbase/Fluid-Template. The template contains only the sentence "Create custom template" because I don´t want to provide a default template.
- Extension "**Layout A**" contains the main template for the website, as well as the template for "Portfolio".

**Cases:**

- When I am logged in as admin always the correct template is used.
- When I am logged out and make "Clear all cache" in install tool the first page I load afterwards gets the correct template. The second/third/... page uses the first and wrong template.

**Settings:**

- "`config.no_cache = 0`" is disabled
- TYPO3 6.2.2
- RealURL enabled
- I added a TypoScript Text-Object with the template path to my fluid template and printed it in fronted. Always the path of the correct, second template.

Does anybody have an idea what´s the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Boris

Comment: You mean, config.no_cache = 1 ?!

Comment: Maybe you should configure the template path via typoscript

Answer (score 0):

Install Tool Clearcache will clear the extbase cahe, so maybe the tempalte paths might be lost.

You should set the path to the templates explicitly via:

```
plugin.portfolio.view {
    layoutRootPath = {$path}
    partialRootPath = {$path}
    templateRootPath = {$path}
}
```